# NppFTP - upload failed (using SFTP)

Tags: sftp, notepad

Using FTP, everything is ok... but..

When i use SFTP, it successfully connects, and even, when i use "UPLOAD BUTTON", it successfully uploads file...
but when i edit+save file, and it starts to upload changes automatically, it cant upload (red message:  file........... upload failed)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have set correct **External Path**.

when using SFTP, external directory should start with: `/home/user/MY_SITE`
(unlike FTP: `/MY_SITE`)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check to ensure that the specific file you are trying to upload has the correct permissions. The **user** should be able to **write**.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are trying to upload should have read and write permission for the user you are using and also check that the owner name & owner group for the file are correct.

I faced this issue and the problem was the user which i was using was not in the owner group for which the file permissions were given.